# How to block one specific Key in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Sorry for this probably easy question but I just find nothing I do understand.
I just need to block a key within a textbox... let say "_" ... So I want to allow all signs except underscore

Here is what I have sofar...

```
private void inputName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(inputName.Text, @"_"))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

... but actually I do not understand how regex works and how I can use for my need.
Thank for every help.

I have solved the poblem by...

```
inputName.Text = inputName.Text.Replace("_", "");
```

on LostFocus Event of this textbox... but of course this is not nice

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how `e.Handled` works even after reading the docs, but did you try different inputs (what should and what shouldn't pass)? Because I get the feeling you should have `if (Regex.IsMatch(inputName.Text, @"_"))` instead.

Comment: I tried this ... after enter underscore once every key is blocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is better solution, for Underscore "_" :

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == (VirtualKey)(189))
    {
         e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Virtual key code for other special characters:

> Semicolon (;) 186 Colon (:)   186 Plus (+)    187
>   Equals sign (=)   187 Comma (,)   188 Less than sign (<)  188 Minus (-)   189
>   Underscore (_)    189 Period (.)  190 Greater than sign (>)   190 Question
>   mark (?)  191 Forward slash (/)   191 Backtick (`)    192 Tilde (~)   192
>   Opening square bracket ([)    219 Opening curly bracket ({)   219 Backslash
>   ()   220 Pipe (|)    220 Closing square bracket (])  221 Closing curly
>   bracket (})   221 Single quote (')    222 Double quote (")    222

Comment: This work perfect! Thank you very much also for the list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match an underscore, you will need something like `"[_]"` In regex, you match a single character by wrapping it in square brackets.